# Using Apache Avro in javascript

Tags: javascript, avro

Is there a means to use Avro on the client side through javascript and REST or RPC or websocket?

If so, with with js library?

Answer (score 9):

**[avsc](https://github.com/mtth/avsc)** a pure JavaScript implementation of the [Avro specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html) and it might be the solution you are looking for.

avsc is compatible with all versions of node.js since 0.11 and **major browsers via browserify** (see the full compatibility table [here](https://github.com/mtth/avsc/wiki#browser-support)). For convenience, you can also find compiled distributions with the releases (but please host your own copy).

I did a small lab and shared my experimental coding with **avsc** in a github repo: [avro-rest-js](https://github.com/rondinif/avro-rest-js), in this demo project there are examples of both client-side and server-side-rest-API in javascript exchanging avro buffers in request/response.

An example of use of **avsc** for RPC websocket look at https://github.com/mtth/verdon a sample Avro remote logging service running behind a WebSocket server and a corresponding client.